# How to make js "for" loop more efficient?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am wondering how to make the loop below more efficient. On my page it has more iterations than 100, that is why, as you can imagine it is troublesome.

```
    for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i += 1) {
        var el = document.createElement('div');
        el.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Node ' + (i + 1)));
        document.getElementById('nodeHolder').appendChild(el);
    }
```

Thanx for help in advance.

Comment: Not sure what the goal is... is it creating 1000 divs each with some text inside? Least you could do is pull document.getElementById('nodeHolder') out of the loop and assign to a variable so you don't have to re-get it every time...

Answer (score 3):

All I can really suggest is getting a reference to the `nodeHolder` element outside of the for:

```
var nodeHolder = document.getElementById('nodeHolder');

 for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i += 1) {
    var el = document.createElement('div'); 
el.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Node ' + (i + 1)));
    nodeHolder.appendChild(el);
 }
```

Or perhaps using a document fragment to hold the interim changes/appends and then add that to to the nodeHolder after the loop:

```
var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i += 1) {
    var el = document.createElement('div'); 
    el.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Node ' + (i + 1)));
    fragment.appendChild(el);
}

document.getElementById('nodeHolder').appendChild(fragment.cloneNode(true));
```

[JS Fiddle showing both approaches](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/wWNVL/) (with timing if the console is available).

Comment: I'll go look it up too, but what is the advantage of using a fragment over just using `var fragment = createElement("div")`? Other than the fact that it means a div will be wrapping everything when `fragment` gets appended? Or is that the main/only difference?

Comment: Document fragments are much faster to manipulate especially before it gets added to the DOM proper.

Comment: See this article on how documentFragment speeds up DOM manipulation: http://ejohn.org/blog/dom-documentfragments/

Comment: Also, your impression that a documentFragment is a div is wrong. DocumentFragments wraps nothing. When inserting the documentFragment all the child nodes become the child nodes of the parent div instead.

Comment: @slebetman: thank you for the edit (composing on Android is... *tedious* at best)! And you're absolutely right, I almost always forget to `appendChild(fragmentIdentifier.cloneNode(true));` on the first run, edited, and corrected. =)

Comment: is the cloneNode necessary... shouldn't just `.appendChild(fragment)` suffice??

Comment: @sErVerdevIL: actually, [it appears `cloneNode` *is* unnecessary](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/wWNVL/1/). Weird (I think I perhaps followed the (previously-linked) ejohn approach too literally, and didn't understand his reason for the `cloneNode`. Tsk.). It doesn't noticeably affect the timing though, but it is still (apparently) unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery way...

```
var d = '';
for(var i=0;i<1000;i++) d += '<div>Node ' + (i + 1) + '</div>';
$('#nodeHolder').append(d);
```

Or javascript inside html...

```
<div id="nodeHolder">
<script>(function() { for(var i=0;i<1000;i++) document.write('<div>Node ' + (i + 1) + '</div>'); })();</script>
</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't exactly help to make the original more efficient. I'm not sure which would be better - appending a (large) amount of HTML in one call (your solution) or making individual `.append` calls for each loop.

Comment: appending at the end has been long said to be more efficient, less additions to the DOM

Answer (score 1):

Maybe: You could generate a HTML String in the for loop like:

```
<div>Node 1</div><div>Node 2</div>
```

and then set the .innerHTML property of nodeHolder to this string after the whole loop is completed.

(... and let the DOM renderer figure out how to best optimize the action)

Answer (score 1):

In summary:

1. Cache your DOM selector.
2. Ditch the for loop, and go for a reverse while loop.
3. Only append your element to the DOM once. The DOM is almost always the bottleneck.

In this pattern, you can take advantage of a reverse loop:

```
//Cache the DOM element
var node = document.getElementById('nodeHolder'),
    markup = [];

//Run the loop backwards for additional speed
var i = 10000;
while(i--){
  markup.push('<div>Node ' + (i + 1) + '</div>');
}

//Reverse the array, join it, then set the innerHTML
node.innerHTML = markup.reverse().join('');​
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/ZAkMZ/3/

Reverse while loop speed reference: https://blogs.oracle.com/greimer/entry/best_way_to_code_a

jQuery version:

```
//Cache the DOM element
var node = $('#nodeHolder'),
    markup = [];

//Run the loop backwards for additional speed
var i = 10000;
while(i--){
  markup.push('<div>Node ' + (i + 1) + '</div>');
}

//Reverse the array, join it, then set the innerHTML
node.append(markup.reverse().join(''));​
```

Comment: the key is point 3, the others are irrelevant changes that you should only change if your comfortable with the new method. IMO stick with what you usually do. If you can visually recognize a for loop easier than a while, use the for.

Comment: Caching the selector is pretty important, too, in my opinion (especially if you are using jQuery or a similar library). Anything DOM-related, really, should be done the least number of times as possible.

Comment: yeah I'd agree with that as well

Answer (score 1):

You definitely need to use DocumentFragment as suggested by @David Thomas.
The most efficient version as I see is this... `cloneNode` is always better than `createElement`, switching between shallow or deep copy (*still faster than createEl*) as required.

Not that it gives a significant gain but you should shy away from assignments when you can. Store data in variables only when you need to. Of course when it comes to readability it's a different thing.

```
var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
var tplEl = document.createElement('div');
var contentTpl = document.createTextNode('Node ');

for (var i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
    var curNode = contentTpl.cloneNode(false);
    curNode.nodeValue = curNode.nodeValue + i;
    tplEl.cloneNode(false).appendChild(curNode);
    fragment.appendChild(tplEl);
}

document.getElementById('nodeHolder').appendChild(fragment);
```

Note that adding the `fragment` to the `nodeHolder` adds all childs of `fragment` as childs to `nodeHolder` triggering only 1 flow as opposed to 1000 flows in your earlier code.

Reference: [Speeding up JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/javascript-dom)

Comment: Apparently if you retain the document.createTextNode() inside the for-loop the console timings move from 3-4ms to 2-3ms.

Answer (score 0):

May be this way:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i+=1) {
  $("<div/>").appendTo("body").attr({"class":'txtHolder'});
  $(".txtHolder").append(i+1);
```

}​